# How to parse search string without fields limit in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I was writing an indexer interface and designed a method:

```
List<MyDocument> search(String query, int start, int end);
```

This method just like `jdbc` search method: pass an `sql` string and return.

But when I tried to use *lucene* to implement, i didn't find a way to parse query string into an Query Object.

I know QueryParser and MultiFieldQueryParser but they need pre-preparedly specify the fields to be searched. In my interface, which fields will be searched doesn't pre-know.

For example:

`(title: help) AND (author: me) AND (content: plz)`

Field `title`, `author` and `content` is pre-unknown. How to build a Query for these pre-unknown fields searching in *lucene*?

Is there any way can help me?

Answer (score 2):

The field argument to QueryParser is the *default* field.  That is, when a field isn't explicitly provided in the query, it will use that field.  So, if I gave it "default" as my default field, and then passed it: `title:help AND stuff`  That is, like this:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("default", new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = parser.parse("title:help AND stuff");
```

It would interpret that as: `title:help AND default:stuff`

The syntax you've provided will work as you intend, regardless of what default field you pass the QueryParser.

Comment: Your example provide two fields, title and default. If I process this string, I must specify "title" for QueryParser at least. The problem is I don't know which filed will be passed, or  you means I must write a syntax analyzer and analyze out the word "title"...

Comment: For the query: `(title: help) AND (author: me) AND (content: plz)`, the default field argument ***does not matter***.  You do *not* need to pass title, author, or content into the parser in order to use them in your query string.

Comment: What I concern is resolving of query string, not query string itself. Constructing a QueryParser object should specify a field, my problem is how to resolve needed fields from query string. I hope lucene has APIs like jdbc which can auto parse sql string.